# Admob banner loading twice resulting two Admob ads in same place

Tags: admob

This is how my admob banner implemented.

in Layout.xml

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/banner_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        android:minHeight="50dp" />
```

In AdActivity.java

```
    private void initBannerViewGroup() {
        bannerViewGroup = findViewById(getBannerViewGroupId());
        if (bannerViewGroup != null) {
            if (shouldShowBannerAd())
                initAdView();
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "Banner view group was not initialized! Wrong id!");
        }
        initInterstitialAd();
    }

private void initAdView() {
        if (mIsPremium){
            bannerViewGroup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return;
        }
        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdUnitId(BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
        bannerViewGroup.addView(adView);
        AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
        adView.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());
    }
```

And called ad in pictureactivity.java

```
    @Override
protected int getBannerViewGroupId() {
    return R.id.banner_layout;
}

@Override
protected boolean shouldShowBannerAd() {
    return true;
}
```

After the above implementation i am getting two banners in same place like follows,
[Admob banner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiTTW.png)
[Admob banner2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkJAZ.png)

If i use only "BANNER" in the place of "SMART_BANNER" only one ad is loading which is fine. But two ads are when used "SMART_BANNER"

Really need a fix for it.

Answer (score 0):

For me, such issue with double banner was related with restarting android Activity by using recreate() method of Activity class.

I fixed the issue by switching on another way of restarting android activity:

startActivity(Intent.makeRestartActivityTask(getActivity().getIntent().getComponent()));

After that, my issue with double banner on the bottom of my app was finally solved.

Answer (score -1):

Implementing the Admob banner as per [this page](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner) solved my issue.

Comment: which part of that entire page did you use to solve the issue?

Comment: @bantingGamer he probably used way with adding banner in the xml. I cant make it work  correctly with adding programmatically SMART_BANNER or FLUID banner or even new Adaptive banner. They all produce double banners for me.